# Converting a rasterfile to a point shapefile with all columns from the rasterfile

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap

I'm trying to convert a raster with multiple columns to a point shapefile to get rid of the "count" column but unfortunately the tool "raster to point" works just for one column so I tried to modify [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33715/how-to-get-values-of-each-cell-in-raster-attribute-table) to write the atribute table to a csv file but it still doesn't work.

I just get a lot of zeros in my outfile. Why am I get just a bunch of zeros?

I'm using ArcMap.

This is the modified code:

```
outfile = Workspace + "/table"

fOut = open(outfile, "wb")               
fOut.write('ID' + ',' + 'Flowaccumaltion' + ',' + 'Flowlength\n') 
rstArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(Combined_Raster) 
rows, cols = rstArray.shape                   
for rowNum in xrange(rows):             
    for colNum in xrange(cols):               
        if colNum == 1 or  colNum == 3:
            value = rstArray.item(rowNum, colNum)   
            fOut.write(str(value) + ',')      
        elif colNum ==4:
            value = rstArray.item(rowNum, colNum)   
            fOut.write(str(value) + '\n')           
fOut.close()
```

This is the raster attribute table I want to convert

[image: Attribute Table]

And I would like to get something like this:

```
ID  , Flowaccumulation,  Flowlength
57  ,    727          ,      1
58  ,     727         ,      1
 0  ,   76073         ,   1008
 1  ,   14919         ,    622
 .  ,      .          ,      .
```

But if there is a tool which can convert a raster to a point shapefile with all fields except for the "count" field then this would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Join Field tool after the converting to points to add the raster fields to the points attribute table. Something like:

```
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(inRaster, outPoint, "value")
arcpy.JoinField_management(outPoint, "rastervalue", inRaster, "value", ["field1","field2", "field3"])
```